# awk - test if print was successful

Tags: function, awk, printing, status

There are a few reasons why a `print` statement in `awk` may not succeed: no permissions to write to the specified file, file doesn't exist and awk can't create it, etc.  How is it possible to test the success of an `awk` `print` statement?  I've tried the following:

```
$ cat printError.awk
BEGIN {
    if (! (print("Hello") > "/this/doesnt/exist")) {
        print "Could not print"
    }
}
```

But it gives a syntax error, I think because print is a statement and not a function.

```
$ awk -f printError.awk 
awk: printError.awk:2:  if (! (print("Hello") > "/this/doesnt/exist")) {
awk: printError.awk:2:         ^ syntax error
awk: printError.awk:2:  if (! (print("Hello") > "/this/doesnt/exist")) {
awk: printError.awk:2:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: printError.awk:2:  if (! (print("Hello") > "/this/doesnt/exist")) {
awk: printError.awk:2:                                                 ^ syntax error
```

EDIT:
I found a solution for gawk 4.2+, but the environment I'm working in has only 4.0, so I'm still looking for a solution for that version.

Answer (score 4):

For gawk 4.2, the answer is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nonfatal.html.  But it seems that PROCINFO["NONFATAL"] is not present in earlier versions.

> 5.10 Enabling Nonfatal Output
>
> This section describes a gawk-specific feature.
>
> In standard awk, output with print or printf to a nonexistent file, or
>   some other I/O error (such as filling up the disk) is a fatal error.
>
> $ gawk 'BEGIN { print "hi" > "/no/such/file" }' error→ gawk: cmd.
>   line:1: fatal: can't redirect to `/no/such/file' (No error→ such file
>   or directory)
>
> gawk makes it possible to detect that an error has occurred, allowing
>   you to possibly recover from the error, or at least print an error
>   message of your choosing before exiting. You can do this in one of two
>   ways:
>
> ```
> For all output files, by assigning any value to PROCINFO["NONFATAL"].
> On a per-file basis, by assigning any value to PROCINFO[filename, "NONFATAL"]. Here, filename is the name of the file to which you wish
> ```
>
> output to be nonfatal.
>
> Once you have enabled nonfatal output, you must check ERRNO after
>   every relevant print or printf statement to see if something went
>   wrong. It is also a good idea to initialize ERRNO to zero before
>   attempting the output

Using the following awk program:

```
$ cat nonFatal.awk 
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["NONFATAL"] = 1
    ERRNO = 0
    print "hi" > "/no/such/file"
    if (ERRNO) {
        print("Output failed:", ERRNO) > "/dev/stderr"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

the error is still fatal in gawk 4.0 and 4.1

```
$ gawk -f nonFatal.awk 
gawk: nonFatal.awk:4: fatal: can't redirect to `/no/such/file' (No such file or directory)
```

But in gawk 4.2.1 it works (I had compiled gawk 4.2.1 as gawk-4.2.1):

```
$ ./gawk-4.2.1 -f /var/tmp/nonFatal.awk 
Output failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Great, well researched answer!